# Laravel 5 : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, laravel, smtp, reset-password

On my Local server everything was good was using mailtrap mail server as smtp server. but when my website is on live server and when I trying to reset password (forgot password ) getting following error screenshot is attached.I am using hostgators cpanels  inbuilt smtp. 
any more details I will provide if needed.[image]

Comment: You're running PHP 7.1 code on an older version

Comment: That questionmark is specifying a nullable type there. This is a functionality introduced in PHP 7.1. Most likely your server is running an older version of PHP.

Comment: @iainn and Niels Thank you for comment. changing php version solved my problem ..  but now getting message that we have emailed you the reset link but I am not getting any mail ..I have checked all gmail folders including spam ... but No MAIL

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to install PHP version 7.1 because [nullable types were introduced in 7.1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php):

```
?string $value
```

And from the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/#installation):

> You will need to make sure your server meets the following requirements:
>
> PHP >= 7.1.3

Comment: changing php version solved my problem .. but now getting message that we have emailed you the reset link but I am not getting any mail ..I have checked all gmail folders including spam ... but No MAIL

Comment: @kohali this is not related to the question. You should accept the answer and create a new one. Attach all related code and information regarding this new issue.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin I'm having same issue with laravel 5.5

Comment: Lifesaver. Thank you so much. it works for me. after 5 hours of reserch

Comment: How to install it?

Answer (score 7):

**For php7.0 only**

If your server doesn't have php 7.1 and above and you are only restricted to use php7.0 
do as below:

1. Delete vendor folder
2. Delete composer.lock file
3. Add this to composer.json file under `config`

   ```
   "platform": {
      "php": "7.0.0"
   }
   ```

As well, ensure PHP version under `require` is set to 7.0.0 as shown below in `config.platform.php`:

```
    "config": {
        "platform": {
            "php": "7.0.0"
        }
     }
```

4. Run composer install using CMD

This now will make sure that only dependencies compatible with php7.0 are installed.

Comment: Does not work. I have Php 7.2 on command line and I want Php 7.0 code base.

Comment: @AhmedNumaan what does not work exactly? Have you run `composer install` after making the changes?

Comment: Code is deployed on shared hosting where composer cannot be installed. So I ran composer command like you mentioned on my PC(Php version 7.2) and then I uploaded vendor directory to the server. It didn't work.

Comment: In your `composer.json`, the dependencies which have been installed, are they compatible with version 7.0 only? If you can verify that, then this could be another issue and not php version issue.